# How will moderator elections work?

Tags: discussion

What's the process for moderator elections?

Do they all follow [this pattern](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-election-begins/)?

Who can initiate elections? And how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nominations for ♦ Moderators starts at about 30 days after the site graduates from beta. That gives sufficient time for users who do not participate in the beta to use the site before nominations and elections.

The *elections* will work much in the same way as the [blog post you linked](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-election-begins/). But we are in the process of putting together a fair and impartial nomination process that does not favor folks to post first to a meta thread.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how they will be run but I seemed to understand from Robert that there would be elections when we left beta.

I have a feeling you know this now also. We need to find a way to communicate easily.

Congrats on Moderator, Joby!

Comment: Thanks. "Moderator Joby" sounds a bit ominous - like "Comrade Duch". I'm keen that the community elect moderators as soon as possible.

Comment: They do it after beta, I should have put a comma between moderator and joby, it was a congrats not a name.

Comment: All moderators do is help the community enforce rules and watch for spambots. I have only had one thing I have taken action on so far, most things we attempt to let the community handle itself.